# Subtracting 5 minutes from epoch date

Tags: java, epoch

What is the best way to subtract 5 minutes from a given epoch date ?

```
public long fiveMinutesAgo(String epochDate) {
//ToDo
return fiveMinBack;
}
```

Comment: Your input is a `String` - what's the format? You should separate tasks into parsing, then arithmetic. Which of those is giving you a problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

epochDate has to be a Date. Use a Calendar:

```
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.setTime(epochDate);
    calendar.add(Calendar.MINUTE, -5);
    Date result = calendar.getTime();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use any of the above mentioned methods by other user , but if  interested give a try to

**Java 8 Date and Time API**

```
public void subtract_minutes_from_date_in_java8 () 
{  
    LocalDateTime newYearsDay = LocalDateTime.of(2015, Month.JANUARY, 1, 0, 0);

LocalDateTime newYearsEve = newYearsDay.minusMinutes(1);// In your case use 5 here 

    java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter formatter =java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss S");  

    logger.info(newYearsDay.format(formatter));

    logger.info(newYearsEve.format(formatter));
}
```

**Output :**

```
01/01/2015 00:00:00 CST
12/31/2014 23:59:00 CST
```

Class **LocalDateTime** is an immutable date-time object present in **java.time** package in **Java 8** that represents a date-time, often viewed as year-month-day-hour-minute-second.

Below is the syntax of `of()` method used :

```
static LocalDateTime    of(int year, int month, int dayOfMonth, int hour, int minute)
```

which obtains an instance of LocalDateTime from year, month, day, hour and minute, setting the second and nanosecond to zero.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a body for your method:

```
private static final long FIVE_MINS_IN_MILLIS = 5 * 60 * 1000;

public long fiveMinutesAgo(String epochDate) throws ParseException { 
    DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm:ss");
    long time = df.parse(epochDate).getTime();
    return time - FIVE_MINS_IN_MILLIS;
}
```

The time is in millis-since-the-epoch, so to find out five minutes before you simply have to subtract 5 mins in milliseconds (5 * 60 * 1000).

I would suggest renaming the method to: `fiveMinutesBefore()` and perhaps breaking it into two methods: one for parsing string dates into times and the other for subtracting minutes from the time.

You might also consider using [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) as it's much better designed (and thread-safer) than the standard Java date package.

Answer (score 0):

You can subtract 5 minute equivalent of miiliseconds from date you get:-

```
//convert input string epochDate to Date object based on the format
long ms=date.getTime();
Date updatedDate=new Date(ms - (5 * 60000)); //60000 is 1 minute equivalent in milliseconds
return updatedDate.getTime();
```